# MySQL Slow Query - Order By

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have the following SELECT that runs in under a second if I remove the ORDER BY at the end. With the ORDER BY it runs in around 9 seconds.

I have a ruff understanding that some other SQL commands like '< >' comparison operators can work adversely with an ORDER BY.

I've tried commenting out lines and can improve the performance to say 2-3seconds with the ORDER BY but still without the ORDER BY its more like under 1 second.

Can someone give me some good advise on how to better write this query, what to avoid etc? All advise is greatly appreciated.

thankyou

Comment: can you please post the result from **EXPLAIN you query** ? How many records are in the resultset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT .. // Your old Query without GROUP BY and LIMIT
  ...  
) AS tmp
ORDER BY heartbeat DESC
LIMIT 120;
```

Comment: @Adam - Why do you remove **) and ORDER BY..** it is important for you query?

Comment: Did this solution really help?  Or was the cache populated, so it _seemed_ to be faster.